# Loading lots of image data (10^9 pixels) into memory

Tags: c++, image, video, video-processing

I'm extracting frames of video to a Surface array to be rearranged into a new video, trading the x dimension with time. Here are some examples of different kinds of effects that come out:  http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=B2540182DE868E85

The app always crashes with `std::bad_alloc` when I try to store 1280 frames of 1280x720 video (1,179,648,000 pixels) into the `Surface[]`. It doesn't crash with 1280 frames of 1080x720 video (995,328,000 pixels).

I made a simple test that makes it work on my computer (4GB RAM), but not on a friend's wimpier laptop:

```
maxWidth = 1920;
while ((inW * inH * maxWidth) >= 1000000000)
  maxWidth -= 20;
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to have fast access to 10^9 pixels than a Surface array?
2. What is this memory limit, and how can I test for it and avoid it when setting up the `maxWidth` for the output?

Big thanks from the C++ noob. I put the source on [Github: Redimensionator](https://github.com/sembiki/Redimensionator/blob/master/src/RedimensionatorApp.cpp). It uses Cinder.

Comment: What is this Surface object, i.e. which framework does it belong to? (It's not standard C++ ... well.. not much is, except std::bad_alloc :)

Comment: Cinder: http://libcinder.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, on a 32-bit platform, your hard limit for address space usage is going to be somewhere around 2GB (but possibly much less) - assuming you keep it all mapped at once. It's best to assume you won't be able to get more than maybe 512MB in contiguous memory, and 1-1.5GB or so in noncontiguous memory (ie, by making multiple small mappings). This is most likely the problem you have; you ran out of contiguous address space. The hardware in turn is limited (for intel CPUs) to somewhere around 16GB of memory for a 32-bit system. And you really, *really* don't want to be swapping. So this means you have one of several options:

- Use a 64-bit system, and a really big array (simple and fast, requires a lot of memory).
- Use a 32-bit system, and a hack to get around address space limits. This tends to mean you'll need to create shared memory objects, and map in only part of the space at a time. On Windows, you can use an [anonymous file mapping object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this - basically shared memory with a NULL name. On Linux, you'll need to first increase the maximum size of /dev/shm, then use [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/shm_open.html) and [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html). (complex, almost as fast as the 64-bit one if done right. Minimize the number of remappings you do. Still needs a lot of memory)
- Use disk files. **Only a real option with a SSD**; on a real disk the seeking will take far too long to be practical. Basically you'd just seek around the file and write out columns of data at a time. (Relatively slow, but not too complex. Requires a SSD. Minimal memory requirements)
- Make multiple passes. You can select a group of output frames to hold in memory at a time; decode the entire video, skipping the parts that correspond to frames you're not holding in memory yet. Once you complete the current set of frames, write them to disk and start over, decoding the video from scratch, with a new set of output frames. This is well suited to massive parallelism - you can break each output set off to another seperate computer to do the work, then stitch them all together in the end. (moderately complex; slow; trades CPU time for memory. Can be very fast if parallelized).

The first two options are good if you have enough memory to hold the entire output video. Ideally you'd want to go the 64-bit route; remapping shared memory windows is an expensive operation, and you'll be doing it a lot.

With the fourth option, it can be difficult to know what the memory limit is. I would recommend doing a binary search using test allocations to figure out how much space in your address space you can use (you should be using low level allocation calls to avoid heap overhead, note). Note that if you're not careful this might not leave any address space for your video decoder - it'd probably be best to subtract 100mb or so from the result and reallocate it to give some room for the normal heap. You should also be careful to stay well below total physical memory, to avoid hitting swap.

Without knowing your OS and what library you're getting that `Surface` class from, it's hard to be more specific about how to probe it - but you really should avoid keeping it in the normal heap, just to avoid allocation errors in other code that's possibly not instrumented to deal with OOMs.

As a side note, you may want to rotate the output frames 90 degrees while preparing them (that is, put them into [column major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order)). You can then rotate them back as a final pass after constructing all the raw images (or even when encoding from raw image data to a compressed format). This is especially important if you decide to go with the disk route with a SSD - it will help avoid unnecessary reads and writes, as with row major order (the usual order for videos) you will have to skip over the pixels for other columns whenever you write one. With in-memory work, though, it's still helpful, as it improves cache locality.

Comment: I'm doing option 4 already, which makes it work on my machine. For running it on other people's machines, I'd like to test for that memory limit (instead of 1000000000) to setup the output dimensions.

Comment: It's difficult to know _a priori_ how much space you can allocate. I'd recommend doing a binary search to see what the upper limit is experimentally.

Comment: @forresto, I've added some additional notes

Comment: Thanks... I think I have some direction with this now. 

I'm on 64-bit OSX, but have not tried compiling the app as 64-bit. I'm using Cinder.

Comment: Any hints on how to implement this binary search memory limit test?

Comment: Same way as with any other binary search - your comparator in this case is an attempt to allocate. If the allocation fails, your current position is too high, and you need to reduce it. If it succeeds, your current position is too low (or equal to the target).

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends on your hardware/os/software/compiler.

- Do you run on an 32-bit or 64-bit OS?
- Do you compile your app to 32-bit or 64-bit?
- Do you allocate it all at once or in chunks (say each frame separately)?
- Do you really need all of the images in memory at the same time, or can you partition your work?

Yes on the latter part of each question makes it easier for you to use a large array.

Comment: I'll try and compile it as 64-bit. I am partitioning the work with `maxWidth`, and I'm trying to figure out what the memory limit that I'm hitting is so that I can test for it more effectively than `((inW * inH * maxWidth) >= 1000000000)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store 1 billion pixels, and each pixel has a color, 24 bit? Assuming you do have 1GB of memory available you would be able to use a 256-color palette and store one pixel a byte.

Trying to store it in contiguous memory is more likely to fail. If you use std::deque you have more chance of being able to fit a large amount into memory.

You have limited address space, by the way, even if your system has the RAM.

Assuming 256 colors is not enough, you may go for 65536 colors which would use 2 bytes a pixel but that would require 2GB. 64-bit address space would help you here. Full 24-bit color would require at least 3GB and more likely you would use 4GB for proper alignment.

In the long term you will probably not want to store it all in memory if you want high resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not allocate storage for one frame at a time until the OS fails to allocate memory? This way, you don't need to bother of 32 vs. 64 bit or shared memory. The only price is an extra indirection.

The point is, there is not really a good and platform-independent way to determine the size of the largest block that the operating system can give you (it depends on a lot of factors ... virtual address space fragmentation, amount of physical memory available (including swapspace) , quota).

Comment: Yes, you can always use `try {} catch() {}` to respond to the `bad_alloc` thrown if the allocation fails.